# Orderby Title not working

Tags: order, sort

When I'm trying to sort my blog posts or my woocommerce in alphabetical order nothing changes. If I access the /?orderby=title-asc or ?orderby=title-desc it brings me the same results.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be `/?orderby=title&order=ASC` or `/?orderby=title&order=DESC`

Comment: Nothing changed ...

Answer (score 0):

André’s answer works `/?orderby=title&order=ASC`, or you can [use a query in a template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Alphabetizing_Posts). You can also sort with the plugin [Post Types Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/).

Comment: It may be right in theory, but unfortunately it doesn't do anything on my site. I suspect that the theme overwrites something.